# How often does Laravel set cache, is it possible to set view auto-cache frequency?

Tags: laravel, caching

I understand it's possible to set cached values by `Cache::set` like [it mentions in the documentation](https://laravel.com/docs/10.x/cache), however, i am not sure how does the frontend view cache work.

Is there some way to define frontend view caching? I have simple blog portal with some articles and their relationships (tags/categories/etc). Now, the content doesn't really change unless administrator creates a new article and there is no need to run the queries every time someone opens a page.

Does Laravel somehow automatically re-renders the view only in case the data is changed? In case it does (**not sure it does though, couldn't find it anywhere**), how would i override this behavior? Like, i also display amount of article-reads, and this is the number that, of course, changes with every opened blog post and it would then mean that the frontend cache would have to be rebuilt. This is not very useful though and it would be sufficient that it would re-fresh amount of article views every few minutes, regardless of the fact that the data have changed.

Could someone help shed some light on this?

Comment: Laravel doesn't automatically cache any results from database queries (if that's how you store articles). It also does not really cache views, (it recomplies them every time and stores the compiled view in the storage folder). If you need things cached you need to implement this manually using `Cache::set` for example.

Comment: In addition, you can implement cache setting logic in custom middleware (i.e. `CacheEveryRequestMiddleware`) which should be called by every route [you need].